# How to autofilter for given strings in common spreadsheet softwares?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, libreoffice

I know I can create an "autofilter" at the top of an XLS table.. But how can I create a filter that filters for given strings?

example TABLE input:

```
LASFD@FOO.COM
LKXYCVER@FOO.COM
salfdajlfd@sadfjasdf.com
LAKSJDFA@LASJFDSA.COM
SADLKFJALD@BAR.COM
```

after filter (filter for @FOO.com and @BAR.com):

```
LASFD@FOO.COM
LKXYCVER@FOO.COM
SADLKFJALD@BAR.COM
```

Comment: You're asking for several programs at the same time. Given there's one Answer for Excel, one for OpenOffice and one for LibreOffice, which one would you accept? You can only accept one answer.

Comment: at least for OpenOffice:\ sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the instruction for Open Office:

- Go to the top tool bar, and select Data.
- Proceed to Select Filter and then Auto Filter.
- Go to the column header of the email addresses you want to filter, click the dropdown, and select Standard Filter.
- Enter the relevant fields: “ends with” for condition and “foo.com” for value 
  OR “ends with” for condition and “bar.com” for value

That should give you the result you need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is going to depend heavily upon what version of Excel you're using, but here are two ways of doing it:

**Option One - A Helper Column**
In a new column in your table enter the following formula:

> =IF(OR(RIGHT([@Addresses],LEN([@Addresses])-FIND("@",[@Addresses]))="foo.com",RIGHT([@Addresses],LEN([@Addresses])-FIND("@",[@Addresses]))="bar.com"),1,0)

Now this is one ugly formula, it works in that you can now filter on all instances of 1 in this column, but what if you wanted to filter on something else?

This is where the best option comes in, though it's also the option most dependant on what you're using. I'm using Office Excel 2013.

**Option Two - Text Filters**
If you go to the Auto Filter dropdown you may find a feature called Text Filters. This will allow you to specify a huge range of methods on which to filter your data:

[image: Text Filters]

Click this and then set up your text filters. Here you can see the filters you've mentioned in your question:

[image: ends with filters]

This will give you far more flexibility, but as I said; it's far more dependent on what you're using.

Comment: Many Thanks! are there any hints for OpenOffice or Libreoffice? :O

Comment: I don't use either of these. Still I'm assuming these should help: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Filters, https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=custom+auto+filter+excel+open+office&meta=#hl=en&q=custom+autofilter+excel+libreoffice&safe=active&spell=1 (I'm getting certificate errors on the LibreOffice sites so this is just the Google search.)